# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays error ng0900

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, firebase

this is original private method.

```
    private cargarEquipo() {

      this.http.get("https://pratice-fe972-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json")
      .subscribe( (resp: any) => {

        this.equipo = resp;
        console.log(resp);
      } )
    }
```

gave me an error :

```
core.mjs:7739 
 ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.mjs:27738:1)
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.mjs:3185:42)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2561:1)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2520:1)
    at executeCheckHooks (core.mjs:2452:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9589:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10777:1)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9376:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9630:1)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10731:1)
```

this is my html which its contain the ng:

```
    <div *ngFor="let persona of infoService.equipo" class="animate__animated animate__bounce ae-grid__item item-lg-4 ae-kappa au-mb-3">
      <img [src]="persona.url" alt="" class="au-mb-3">
      <h5 class="ae-u-bolder au-mt-2">{{ persona.nombre }}</h5>
      <p class="ae-u-bolder au-mb-3">{{ persona.subtitulo }}</p>
      <p class="au-lg-ta-left au-mb-3 au-pl-4 au-pr-4">{{ persona.frase }}</p>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/{{ persona.twitter }}" class="ae-u-bolder au-underline">{{ persona.twitter }}</a>
    </div>
```

my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InfoPaginaService } from 'src/app/services/info-pagina.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( public infoService: InfoPaginaService  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

and my service.ts too:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { infoPagina } from '../interfaces/info_pagina.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InfoPaginaService {

  info: infoPagina = {};
  cargada: boolean = false;
  equipo: any [] = [];

  constructor ( private http: HttpClient ) {

    this.cargarInfo();
    this.cargarEquipo();
    }


    private cargarInfo() {

      this.http.get('assets/data/data_pagina.json')
      .subscribe( (resp: infoPagina) => {

        this.cargada = true;
        this.info = resp;
        console.log(resp);
      } )

    }

    private cargarEquipo() {

      this.http.get("https://pratice-fe972-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json")
      .subscribe( (resp: any) => {

        this.equipo = resp;
        console.log(resp);
      } )
    }
   }
```

i tried to fix this error doing this:

```
 private cargarEquipo() {

      this.http.get("https://pratice-fe972-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json")
      .subscribe( (resp: any[]) => {

        this.equipo = resp;
        console.log(resp);
      } )
    }
```

but it gave me this error too:

```
src/app/services/info-pagina.service.ts:36:19 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<Object>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(resp: any[]) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<Object>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: Object) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(resp: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'resp' and 'value' are incompatible.
        The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
          Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(resp: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'resp' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
          The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

36       .subscribe( (resp: any[]) => {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

Always Check the response of your http. You see that it's an object with a property "equipo" (is this property where is stored the array). So you should use

```
this.http.get("https://pratice-fe972-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json")
      .subscribe( (resp: any[]) => {

        this.equipo = resp.equipo; //<--see that you equal your
                                   //variable "equipo" to the array "equipo" from 
                                   //the response
        console.log(this.equipo);
      } )
```

As suggest, use "plural" when you name a variable that store an array, better your variable called `equipos` than `equipo`

Comment: And i would suggest that you should always create interfaces instead of using any. Bcs interface can instantly gave you hint or error if you trying iterate object instead of array.

Comment: @DanielVágner, an interface only help to you to write the code, but has no effect about you received. That's, you can use `(res:MyInterface[])=>...` but only avoid you don't write, e.g. `res[0].strange_property`

Comment: Yes, that was the intention, that due to typing, it would prevent someone from mistakenly writing:
this.info = resp; instead of resp.equipo.